# Explode en PHP para separar caracteres

Tags: php

Necesito hacer un split o explode en PHP de esta string:

```
$nombre = I_20_IH_21_23_HP_junio.jpg;
```

Tengo que hacer 3 strings separadas por

- `I_ y _I`;
- `H_ y _H`;
- `P_ y` .

He intentado hacer un explode pero no sé como poner un string que lo delimite

```
$nombre = explode ( "I_",$file,"_I",0);
```

Gracias por la ayuda!

Comment: cual deberia ser el resultado para la string $nombre que planteas? es decir, el resultado final que esperas

Comment: @Jakala el resultado sería de 3 strings. El primero "20", el segundo "21_23" y el tercero "Junio"

Comment: Sería importante que digas si es un patrón, o sea, si siempre los datos estarán encerrados por los tres criterios que mencionas. De eso dependerá la conveniencia o no de hacerlo con expresiones regulares, en lo cual @Mariano te echará una mano casi seguro.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

En tu caso, yo utilizaria patrones con preg_match. Te pongo el ejemplo del patron de tu caso (por lo que he entendido, los valores de lo que quieres sacar estan entre I_ e *I, H* y *H y P* y . Entonces tu patron podria ser:

```
/I_(.*)_IH_(.*)_HP_(.*)\./
```

con preg_match le indicas el patron, la cadena y el array donde guardar los resultados.

```
$nombre = "I_20_IH_21_23_HP_junio.jpg"; 
$patron = "/I_(.*)_IH_(.*)_HP_(.*)\./";
$result = preg_match($patron, $nombre, $resultados);

print_r($resultados);
```

En el ejemplo, podrias sacar un array con cuatro elementos, el primero es toda la cadena, y los demas son cada una de las subcadenas que buscas.

En resultado tendrias un array como el siguiente:

```
Array
(
    [0] => I_20_IH_21_23_HP_junio.
    [1] => 20
    [2] => 21_23
    [3] => junio
)
```

Tus valor de I esta en el indice 1, el H en indice2 y el P en indice 3

Answer (score 1):

Un truco para evitar el uso de expresiones regulares cuando no las dominas, es reemplazar todos los delimitadores por un mismo delimitador en la cadena a explotar:

```
$nombre = 'I_20_IH_21_23_HP_junio.jpg'; 
$delimitadores=['I_','_I', 'H_', '_H', 'P_', '.'];

$nombre_modificado = str_replace($delimitadores,'|',$nombre);

echo $nombre_modificado;
```

Te entrega:

```
|20||21_23||_junio|jpg
```

Y eso ya puedes trabajarlo explotando simplemente por `|`. Pero fíjate que tu texto original dará lugar a elementos vacíos en el array, debido a separadores consecutivos y al separador al inicio de la cadena. Eso te queda de tarea.

Comment: no conocia ese sistema @amenadiel. Es curioso, cambias los delimitadores por un delimitador. Como detalle,tienes confundido uno de los delimitadores, el Y_ es P_. Por favor, cambialo en tu respuesta para que sea coherente. Gracias

Comment: editado. gracias!